# Integrate Chatbot into a website without using iframes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, botframework, chatbot

I have created a chatbot using the Microsoft Bot Framework and now I want to integrate it into my website without using iframes but I have no idea how to do it.
Can you please help me?
Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: please take a look at the readme on [this repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have built a [React component](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#medium-in-your-react-website-incorporate-the-web-chat-react-component) as an alternative to using iFrames.

```
import { Chat } from 'botframework-webchat';

...

const YourApp = () => {
    <div>
        <YourComponent />
        <Chat directLine={{ secret: direct_line_secret }} user={{ id: 'user_id', name: 'user_name' }}/>
        <YourOtherComponent />
    </div>
}

...
```

EDIT:

First you need to install the react chatbot component. Run `pm install botframework-webchat` in your terminal. That will install a new package called `botframework-webchat`. Then in your main `<App />` component, you need to import the component from the package like this: `import { Chat } from 'botframework-webchat';`.

Now you have access to the `<Chat />` component and can use it just like any other component. You need to supply two props to this component: your `direct_line_secret` and `user` info.

That's it!

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to use this approach.
I am a beginner and this is my 1st project

Comment: @dannywallock Sure, updated my answer.